# Mostrar la fecha del comentario excepto cuando se ha escrito el mismo día

Tags: php

Supongamos que tengo un comentario de hace un par de días y otro de esta misma mañana. Para mostrar la fecha de hace dos días lo dejo en `20 Nov 2018` pero en la de hoy quiero que ponga `Hoy, 14:00.`

Cómo lo hago para que con `Datetime` me devuelva ese valor?

```
$fecha = $fechaCreacion->format('j M Y');
```

Me devuelve día mes y año. Y quiero que ponga Hoy (en caso de que el comentario sea del mismo día en el que se visualiza) y la hora en cuestión. No creo que pueda ser más preciso.

Comment: Bienvenido a Stackoverflow. Para ayudarte, es preciso que indiques lo que has intentado y el problema que tienes, en qué parte del código te quedas bloqueado. Gracias.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Te dejo un pequeño ejemplo, que compara la fecha de hoy, con otro y según la diferencia determina si es "**Hoy**", "**Ayer**", "**Mañana**" o ninguna de las anteriores.

```
$timestamp = "2018.01.22T09:14"; // La fecha de tu comentario - Como sea que la obtengas 

$today = new DateTime(); // Aca tendrias la fecha y hora actual
$today->setTime( 0, 0, 0 ); // Reset de la hora para evitar comparacion parcial

$match_date = DateTime::createFromFormat( "Y.m.d\\TH:i", $timestamp );
$match_date->setTime( 0, 0, 0 ); // Reset de la hora para evitar comparacion parcial

$diff = $today->diff( $match_date );
$diffDays = (integer)$diff->format( "%R%a" ); //Calcula la diferencia de dias en el intervalo

switch( $diffDays ) {
    case 0:
        echo "//Hoy";
        break;
    case -1:
        echo "//Ayer";
        break;
    case +1:
        echo "//Mañana";
        break;
    default:
        echo "//Algun otro dia";
}
```

> [Aquí](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) puedes ver los diferentes formatos para la fecha, dependiendo de como tu la almacenes. Para hacer `createFromFormat()`.

Comment: Perfecto , gracias!